# Convert PHP array to specific JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have trying to generate specific json for Rubrics which require this below format only .

Why I need this ?
https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=questiontype-matrix-rubric&platform=jQuery&theme=bootstrap#content-js

For surveyJS it i am creating cells json using PHP

PHP output

```
Array
(
    [Attendance] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [OUTSTANDING] => A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Satisfactory] => B
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Needs Improvement] => C
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Unacceptable] => D
                )

        )

    [Punctuality] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [OUTSTANDING] => A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Satisfactory] => B
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Needs Improvement] => C
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Unacceptable] => D
                )

        )

)
```

Output I have been trying to achieve and required

```
               {
                    "Attendance": {
                        "OUTSTANDING": "A",
                        "Satisfactory": "B",
                        "Needs Improvement": "C",
                        "Unacceptable": "D"
                    },
                    "Punctuality": {
                        "OUTSTANDING": "A",
                        "Satisfactory": "B",
                        "Needs Improvement": "C",
                        "Unacceptable": "D"
                    }
                }
```

This is what I have tried so far :-

```
 $finalArr = [];
            $columns = [];
            $rows = [];
            $cells = [];
            $rubics = json_decode($model->rubric_json);
            $points = json_decode($model->points_json);
            $rubicsCols = json_decode($model->rubric_json);

            if (!empty($rubicsCols[0])) {
                $columns = array_filter($rubicsCols[0], 'strlen');
            }

            if (!empty($points[0])) {
                $points = array_filter($points[0], 'strlen');
            }
            unset($rubics[0]);
            if (!empty($rubics)) {
                foreach ($rubics as $key => $data) {
                    $rows[] = [
                        'value' => $data[0],
                        'text' => $data[0]
                    ];
                }
            }

            if (!empty($rows)) {
                foreach ($rows as $rowKey => $row) {
                    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
                        $cells[$row['text']][] =[
                            $column =>$rubics[$rowKey + 1][$key]
                        ] ;
                    }
                }
            }


            echo "<pre>";
            print_r(json_encode($cells,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));exit;
```

after json_encode($cells,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) output is :-

```
{
    "Attendance": [
        {
            "OUTSTANDING": "Attends all of class.Never arrives late, leaves early, or is in and out of the class while it is in progress."
        },
        {
            "Satisfactory": "Attends most of class.Rarely arrives late, leaves early, or is in and out of the class while it is in progress."
        },
        {
            "Needs Improvement": "Sometimes absent.Sometimes arrives late, leaves early, or is in and out of the class while it is in progress."
        },
        {
            "Unacceptable": "Often absent.Often arrives late, leaves early, or is in and out of the class while it is in progress."
        }
    ],
    "Punctuality": [
        {
            "OUTSTANDING": "Always ready to start when class starts at the beginning of the day and when class resumes after breaks."
        },
        {
            "Satisfactory": "Usually ready to start when class starts at the beginning of the day and when class resumes after breaks."
        },
        {
            "Needs Improvement": "Rarely ready to start when class starts at the beginning of the day and when class resumes after breaks."
        },
        {
            "Unacceptable": "Almost never ready to start when class starts at the beginning of the day and when class resumes after breaks"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @xtraorange I have added an edit Sorry

Comment: no worries, it just helps provide better answers when you include that

Comment: Sure thanks mate its my first time @xtraorange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten each sub-array.  Given that structure this should work:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key] = array_merge(...$val);
}
```

If you have an old PHP version then:

```
    $array[$key] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $val);
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate I was banging my head for last 4-5 hours You saved my time ,I learned something new .God bless

Comment: It would be easier just to build it properly first, but you didn't show that earlier.  If you give an example of `$columns`  , `$rubrics` and `$points` it's probably much easier.

Comment: You are right actually and I have just built my own thing now . Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 2):

According to [json.org](https://www.json.org) specification an associative array will be converted to an object and flat one will be an array, so you need something like:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'Attendance' => [
        'OUTSTANDING' => 'A',
        'Satisfactory' => 'B',
        'Needs Improvement' => 'C',
        'Unacceptable' => 'D'
    ],
    'Punctuality' => [
        'OUTSTANDING' => 'A',
        'Satisfactory' => 'B',
        'Needs Improvement' => 'C',
        'Unacceptable' => 'D'
    ]
];

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```